# remove redirection in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

I'm trying to removeredirection to wp-login after I've moved the wp installation in a subdirectory for security issues. How can I remove the redirection from myurl.wyz/wp-admin? I want to access the backend from myurl.xyz/wp-subdirectory/wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the location of your wp-admin folder, you will face a lot of issues to keep things working. I would not suggest so actualy move this folder somewhere else.

You are talking about security, so I think you don't want the backend to be found with wp-admin because every wordpress user knows this path.

So there is a plugin for changing the url of your backend login. This will make your site more save, because the login form cannot be found that easy: https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-admin-login/

**EDIT**: If you want to have custom redirection, you can create a plugin and adjust the code for your needs:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Redirect Wordpress Admin pages
    Description: Redirect if accessed
    Version: 1.0
*/


add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if( ( is_admin() ) ) {
        if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/wp-subdirectory/wp-admin' ) );
            exit();
        }
    }

});


add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
    function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already change the folder directory. all things is working right. I only want to remove redirection, in order to hide the url with the subdirectory. Do I have to modify wp-login.php or wp-admin.php file? By the way thank you Rank!

Comment: Ok, I think you just want to redirect if a url is accessed. Take a look at my edited answer